# update one level array use any version i need update please suggest here

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoDb in my application. Here I am facing problem in querying database.
  **My query is  :**

I want to set a field children.cars.carname = 'vws' on query condition children.cars.carmodel =22.

```
db.selectone.update({'children.cars':{$elemMatch:{'carmodel':22}}},{$set:{'children.cars.$.carname':'vws'}});
            WriteResult({
                "nMatched" : 0,
                "nUpserted" : 0,
                "nModified" : 0,
                "writeError" : {
                    "code" : 16837,
                    "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (children of children.cars.0.carname) to traverse the element ({children: [ { cars: [ { carname: \"tata\", carmodel: 23.0 }, { carname: \"nano\", carmodel: 22.0 } ] } ]})"
            }
        })
```

**collection name is selectone :**

```
  [
  {
    title: "Parent1",
    children: [
      {
        cars: [
          {
            carname: 'tata',
            carmodel:23
          },
          {
            carname:'nano',
            carmodel:22
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    title: "Parent2",
    children: [
      {
        cars: [
          {
            carname:'volvo',
            carmodel:22
          },
          {
            carname:'maruthi',
            carmodel:25
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your children is an array:

```
{
    title: "Parent1",
    children: [{
        cars: [{
            carname: 'tata',
            carmodel:23
          },{
            carname:'nano',
            carmodel:22
        }]
    }]
}
```

of one object `{cars: [...]}`. And when you make an update you are referring to it as an object. If you will change your schema to

```
{
        title: "Parent1",
        children: {
            cars: [{
                carname: 'tata',
                carmodel:23
              },{
                carname:'nano',
                carmodel:22
            }]
        }
   }
```

notice that now children is an object, it should work. Also please keep in mind that the idea of schema less documents in database, does not mean that you can throw anything in your collection with tens of levels of nestings inside of arrays and then somehow hope to create a query to use it. The idea is that schema is not as rigid as in RDBMs.

Comment: I need children should be an array containing cars and further more i can insert diffrent types of vechilcles in children:[ { cars:[] } ]

Comment: @NareshKumar got it. Sorry, but in this case I do not know how to achieve this. At least I told you the reason for the error. I would suggest you to update the question, so that other people would know that you really need the array of children